# Redirect URL based on JSON callback data

Tags: javascript, json, geoip

I tried to use JavaScript to redirect visitors by country

The following call checks the IP of the country by visitor e.g. CN (China) and redirects it to an other web site.

```html
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
  function geoip(json) {
    var countrycode.textContent = json.country;
  }

  if (countrycode.textContent == "CN") {
    window.location = "http://baido.com"
  }
</script>
```

Any help?

Comment: At some point you'll need to call `geoip`.

Comment: how to do it ?.

Comment: Actually, he does not have to call on the function, the library does that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that there is an answer marked solved, however I still couldn't get that to work. So I created this, just in case you want to go in another direction:

```js
  function geoip() {
  
   $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['country'] == "CN") {
              window.location = "https://baido.com/";
            }
     }
    });
    }
    
geoip();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the example code properly. The `countrycode.textContent` part is supposed to show the user's country code on the browser which means it would not work for your use case since you are trying to redirected.

Also note that the `geoip` function is used by the script you loaded from `geojs` so if you are trying to redirect, you should do that in that function.

Here is the updated code that works.

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function geoip(json){
            if (json.country_code == "CN") {
              window.location = "http://baido.com/";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
```